# how can i add phone number field from class profile to class user?

Tags: django, class, model, phone-number

I need to add phone number into my required model's field, so I'm doing this but is not working correctly
so if everyone knows how can I add a Phone number, please help me:

```
#models.py

    from django.db import models
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
        from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
        
        
        class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
            def create_user(self, phone_number, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
                if not email:
                    raise ValueError("User Must have an Email Address")
                if not password:
                    raise ValueError("User Must have a Password")
                if not phone_number:
                    raise ValueError("User Must have a Phone Number")
                user_obj = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
                user_obj.set_password(password)  # change user password
                user_obj.phone_number(phonenumber_field)
                user_obj.staff = is_staff
                user_obj.active = is_active
                user_obj.admin = is_admin
                user_obj.save(using=self._db)
                return user_obj
        
            # staff user
            def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
                user = self.create_user(
                    email,
                    password=password,
                    phone_number=PhoneNumberField,
                    is_staff=True
                )
                return user
            # admin user
        
            def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
                user = self.create_user(
                    email,
                    password=password,
                    phone_number=PhoneNumberField,
                    is_staff=True,
                    is_admin=True
                )
                return user
        
        
        class User(AbstractBaseUser):
            email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
            # full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
            active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # can log in
            staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff user non super user
            admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # super user
            timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
            phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
        
            USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # username
            REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # FULL_NAME
            object = UserManager()
        
            def __str__(self):
                return self.email
        
            def get_full_name(self):
                return self.email
        
            def get_short_name(self):
                return self.email
        
            def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
                return True
        
            def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
                return True
        
            @property
            def is_staff(self):
                return self.staff
        
            @property
            def is_admin(self):
                return self.admin
        
            @property
            def is_active(self):
                return self.active
        
        
        class Profile(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I wanna add phone number in class profile and include this to the required field on user class, but I cant

every time i have error :  **raise TypeError("Can't convert %s to PhoneNumber." % type(value).**name**)
TypeError: Can't convert int to PhoneNumber.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a ModelField class to an attribute. Instead try to pass the value through method arguments. As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model), you should be able to pass the value if the field is required.

So, update your manager method like this:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, phone_number, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User Must have an Email Address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User Must have a Password")
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError("User Must have a Phone Number")
        user_obj = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user_obj.set_password(password)  # change user password
        user_obj.phone_number = phone_number
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    # staff user
    def create_staffuser(self, email, phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            phone_number=phone_number,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user
    # admin user

    def create_superuser(self, email, phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            phone_number=phone_number,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user
```

And add `phone_number` to required fields in model:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number']
```